# Is it OK to cast a std::vector<float>'s internal buffer to char*?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to save a float vector buffer, which has audio, into a file. When the audio is in RAM, i can hear it normally and it's ok. After I save to the file, it's all glitchy.

I'm saving like this:

```
file.write((char *) getCurrentPlayback()->sharedConsumableRotatingBuffer->buffer.data(), sizeInBytes);
```

Where `buffer` is `std::vector<float> buffer;`

I think there's something wrong about me saving lots of `char*` from a `float` vector. Is the cast `(char *) getCurrentPlayback()->sharedConsumableRotatingBuffer->buffer.data()` ok?

`sizeInBytes` is the quantity of floats in the buffer multiplies by `sizeof(float)` so I get the correct number of bytes in it.

`file` is `std::ofstream file`

Comment: If you're okay with non-portable binary formats, maybe? Just be sure your file is in binary mode and doesn't do inadvertent CRLF conversion.

Comment: Without bug reproduction code your question cannot possibly be answered. That's why I voted to close your question. Read help pages on how to ask questions, that question mark navigation button top right.

Comment: C++'s aliasing rules say any object can be viewed as an array of bytes. The reverse is not necessarily true, unfortunately, so getting the proper data out of a stream requires additional precautions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you're doing with the buffer after obtaining a `char *` pointer.

Assuming the output file stream is opened in binary mode, writing to that stream is fine (unless you attempt to write more characters to the buffer than exist, which causes undefined behaviour).   The result will be system specific.

To read the data back in again, the reading program will need to have the same representation of `float` as the writing program.  In practice that means the compilers used to build the writing and reading programs will both need to support the same floating point representation (which can be a concern, if different compilers are used to build the programs and they use different representations).   It is also necessary for the reading program to open the file for reading in binary mode and to resize the buffer BEFORE   reading the data.   (The act of reading a buffer from a binary file does not implicitly resize that buffer - read more data than the buffer can hold, and the behaviour is undefined).

Answer (score 1):

> Is casting `std::vector<float>` internal buffer to char* ok?

Sure.

Note that a file written like this will not be portable to other systems that may use different representation.